# How to deploy plugin.xml to Eclipse installations?

Tags: xml, windows, eclipse, deployment

I made a Plug-in Project (with a pop-up menu) and customized a plugin.xml file so it added a context-menu which launches a 3rd-party application (see the code below).

Now it works on my host only, and I'd like to deploy it to other 20 hosts where Eclipse is installed (i.e. for all developers in my team).

How to integrate it automatically with Eclipse? I.e. I'd prefer to avoid ask the users to run it manually with a 20-steps procedure.

Could it be that we have to copy this file (or another file) to a certain location?

I use Eclipse on Windows only.
Thank you.

**

```
/**
 * @see IActionDelegate#selectionChanged(IAction, ISelection)
 */
public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
    // set selection
    this.selection = selection;
}



public void run(IAction action) {
        // Get file from selection
        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            IStructuredSelection ssel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
            Object obj = ssel.getFirstElement();
            IFile file = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj,
                    IFile.class);
            if (file == null) {
                if (obj instanceof IAdaptable) {
                    file = (IFile) ((IAdaptable) obj).getAdapter(IFile.class);
                }
            }
            if (file != null) {
                // Display Message with selected path
                MessageDialog.openInformation(
                        shell,
                        "MyPlugin Found file",
                        "File path"+file.getFullPath().toOSString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a question on how to actually run the external application, or how to deploy this plug-in to everyone?

Comment: @nitind: It's about how to deploy this plug-in to everyone. I'd appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created an plugin-project containing this plugin.xml. You can create a jar-file for a plugin-project and all the user which want to use it, copy that jar-file into the "dropin" subdirectory of eclipse.

The structure of the JAR file is eclipse specific. Check examples in the "plugins" directory of eclipse. You need the plugin.xml but also an META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and other files of the plugin project.

Without more information about this plugin - its hard to find out what you are doing :-)
So this can be only a startup help for your problem...

Comment: thank you. I edited my question and added more info. Hope this helps.